# Is $L$ the smallest class containing the ordinals and closed under Godel's operations?

Tags: set-theory

A theorem that appears in Jech's *Set Theory* states that a transitive class, M, is an inner model if and only if M is closed under Godel's operations and is almost universal (if $X \subset M$ then there is some $Y\in M$ such that $X\subset Y$).  Since $L$ is the smallest inner model, $L$ is the smallest class that is both closed under Godel operations and almost universal.

It is intuitively clear why there is a smallest class that contains the ordinals and is closed under Godel's operations.  However, it is less intuitive why there would be a smallest class having this quality AND being almost universal.  This would seems to require that the intersection of almost universal classes be almost universal, which I do not see a reason for.
This makes me wonder whether the closure of the ordinals under Godel's operations happens to already be almost universal.

If possible, I am interested in a response that considers classes in the wider sense of NBG set theory; that is, without the assumption that every class corresponds to a formula.

Comment: If you look at this theorem, almost universality is what needed for the power set axiom, the Godel operations for the rest (well, and transitivity for extensionality, foundation, and infinity). You might want to try and show that the closure of the ordinals under Godel operations fails to satisfy the power set axiom (e.g. it has too few subsets of $\omega$). Since Godel operations are absolute, doing them is the same as doing them in $L$, so it suffices to consider the case of $V=L$.